# Grunt is removing scripts and css in index.html

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have app deployed on heroku for some time. I always add components using `bower install` and then grunt to minimize, uglify and concatinate.

**I have used yeoman to generate my Gruntfile.js**

I installed a new library, included it in my index.html and run `grunt` command, it suddenly got removed from my index.html

**On the left side, is what happens after I run Grunt, the right side is before I run grunt command**

[image: Diff of css files removed]

**Here is a diff of the single javascript file removed**
[image: javascript file removed]

Here is the bower.json file

```
{
  "name": "civilization-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "2.4.1",
    "angular": "~1.3.8",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.1",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.7",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.7",
    "angular-touch": "~1.3.7",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.7",
    "angular-utf8-base64": "~0.0.5",
    "angular-messages": "~1.3.8",
    "ng-table": "~0.3.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "~2.0.5",
    "ng-file-upload-shim": "~2.0.5",
    "angular-growl-v2": "~0.7.3",
    "nya-bootstrap-select": "~2.0.8",
    "animate.css": "~3.2.6",
    "angular-bootstrap-simple-chat": "~0.3.1",
    "angularjs-scroll-glue": "~0.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.7",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.3.7"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.3.8"
  }
}
```

**Here is my GruntFile.js**

```
// Generated on 2015-05-12 using generator-angular 0.11.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Configurable paths for the application
    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        yeoman: appConfig,

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['wiredep']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                }
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect().use(
                                '/app/styles',
                                connect.static('./app/styles')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: {
                src: [
                    'Gruntfile.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
                ]
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            server: {
                options: {
                    map: true,
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
                ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            //js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            js: ['concat'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
                ]
            }
        },


        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    conservativeCollapse: true,
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
        // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
        ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
                    src: '*.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        '*.html',
                        'views/{,*/}*.html',
                        'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
                    src: 'fonts/*',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'wiredep',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer:server',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        //'uglify',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

**Does anyone know why Grunt is removing this files when I run Grunt?**

[PS: My code is on github, you can view it there](https://github.com/cash1981/civilization-boardgame-web)

Comment: Both `grunt serve` and `grunt` commands are removing bootstrap.css and angular-bootstrap-simple-chat stuff. Its mindboggling.

Comment: It seems to be related to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16720 but I can't find a workaround

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will explain it with respect to bootstrap.
The wiredep picks files from bower_components/{bootstrap}/bower.json > "main" value.
 The bootstrap css file is not listed in that value. 
For test/fun edit the above mentioned file as below:

```
"moduleType": "globals",
"main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "dist/css/bootstrap.css"
  ],...
```

Notice the ***dist/css/bootstrap.css*** in "main" value.
Now run grunt or grunt build. You will find that ***bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css*** is injected in ***app/index.html*** at the place you are expecting.

This is not the answer to your problem, you can refer to the bug on bootstrap
*https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16663*.

However, my final suggestion would be ***downgrade to bootstrap 3.3.1*** until they decide to resolve it.

Sorry, there is no better solution that I can think of, its "Their" decision.

You can check this for all the libraries that are having issue, either raise an issue at their Repo, or downgrade or wait until it becomes stable.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the bower.json file manually for now. I might downgrade later

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your problem, i have strong intuition that your new bower package must be using different version of common dependent,
For example: you new package might have been downloading latest version of common dependent package, i.e. JQuery and might be downloading it also at the time of installing itself.

and when while wiring dependencies you are facing this problem.

I am not sure but it works like this.